# Why aren't these sentence elements placed in a different way?

Tags: grammar

A: タワポン-さんの部屋はどこですか。
B: あの**カーテンの閉まった**へやです。

I think it translates into this:
A: Which is the apartment of tawapon-san?
B: That apartment with the closed curtains.

I wondered, why isn't the sentence built like this:

B: あの**閉まったカーテン**の部屋です。

At least to me, it seems to be less ambiguous than the original version, which on first sight could also translate into:
B: That closed apartment with curtains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> > A: タワポン-さんの部屋はどこですか。
> > B: あのカーテンの閉まったへやです。
>
> B: あの閉まったカーテンの部屋です。
>
> I think it translates into this: A: Which is the apartment of tawapon-san? B: That apartment with the closed curtains.

閉まったカーテン might be used in some context, but in this case, it's simply an unusual thing to hear to our native ears.

I think it's because the closed curtain is not something expected to be always that way. How would you say the same thing in your language?

The ***state*** of カーテンが閉まっている is the point that we naturally feel that we should say; we want to describe it as a (small but) clause with the subject and the predicate.

あのカーテンの[が]**閉まった**部屋です。

あのカーテンの[が]**閉まっている**部屋です。

These two are natural.

If it's あの赤いカーテンの部屋です, it works just fine. This is plain natural, but あのカーテンの赤い部屋です also works.

Comment: Thanks! Your two examples reminded me of the respective point in the grammar section of my textbook! It is stated there that sometimes, the subject of a sentence element further specifiying a noun may sometimes be marked by の instead of が. 
I entirely forgot about it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## TL;DR:

The original sentence is correct, yours are not correct.

---

There are many ways to achieve that and one of the way is through the use of 修飾語 in the form of 〜た＋名詞。

In your example sentence:

あのカーテンの閉まったへやです。

If we parse the sentence it would be:

あの-> （カーテンの閉まった：部屋）＋です。＝The curtain-closed room.

Which successfully points out which room Mr. Tawapon is in.

However in your own sentence:

あの->  (閉まったカーテン) の 部屋 ＋です。＝The room of the closed curtain.

It sounds like if the curtain owned the house, instead of Mr. Tawapon.

---

This may sound better to you : あのカーテン**が**閉まった部屋

One more example will be：　あのドアの開いた車